# Display an image only when it is fully downloaded and rendered in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to display an image. The image's height and width is dynamic depending on the browser's height and width. How can I only display a div that contains the image only when the image is ready to be displayed?

```
<div id="container">
  <img ng-src="{{media_list.cur}}" />
</div>
```

Do I need to use jQuery for this? I'd like to do as much as possible without any additional libraries (maybe I can use AngularJS's built-in jqlite or something)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work.

```
app.directive('img', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      el.addClass('hide');

      el.on('load', function() {
        el.removeClass('hide');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of what the CSS & HTML components might look like?

Comment: `<img src="path/to/img.jpg">` &

`img.hide { display: none; }` or whichever method of hiding the image you prefer, opacity, visibility etc

Answer (score 1):

Believe you can use the onload property if you want to avoid jQuery:

```
img.onload = function() {
  // image is loaded
}
```

Comment: You have to get the `img` elements from the DOM too, but this would work.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of what the HTML/CSS would look like as well?

Comment: @jyek el.on if jquery is not avaible is not jquery but jqLite see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element